# play mp3 without default player

Tags: python-3.x, pyglet

I'm trying play mp3 without default player use, so I want try pyglet, but nothing works

```
import pyglet

music = pyglet.resource.media('D:/folder/folder/audio.mp3')
music.play()

pyglet.app.run()
```

I've tried  it this way

```
music = pyglet.resource.media('D:\folder\folder\audio.mp3')
```

and like this:

```
music = pyglet.resource.media('D:\\folder\\folder\\audio.mp3')
```

but have this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\pyglet\resource.py", line 624, in media
    location = self._index[name]
KeyError: 'D:\folder\folder\audio.mp3'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/PC/PyCharm_project/0_TEMP.py", line 3, in <module>
    music = pyglet.resource.media('D:\folder\folder\audio.mp3')
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\pyglet\resource.py", line 634, in media
    raise ResourceNotFoundException(name)
pyglet.resource.ResourceNotFoundException: Resource "D:\folder\folder\audio.mp3" was not found on the path.  Ensure that the filename has the correct captialisation.
```

Comment: In your error message, you have a path without the escaping `\\ ` which tells me Python(pyglet) is trying to fetch the file `D:\f...` where `\f` being a escape sequence `^f`which won't work. And the error message probably doesn't apply to the other examples you've given. Do you have the same error message (identical) on the other lines of code?

Comment: yes same error with all slash variants I have above

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the way you load the resource.
Try this code for instance:

```
import pyglet

music = pyglet.media.load(r'D:\folder\folder\audio.mp3')
music.play()

pyglet.app.run()
```

The way this works is that it loads a file and places it in a `pyglet.resource.media` container. Due to namespaces and other things, the code you wrote is only allowed to load resources from the working directory. So instead, you use `pyglet.media.load` which is able to load the resource you need into the current namespace (**Note:** I might be missusing the word "namespace" here, for lack of a better term without looking at the source code of pyglet, this is the best description I could come up with).

You could experiment by placing the `.mp3` in the script folder and run your code again but with a relative path:

```
import pyglet

music = pyglet.resource.media('audio.mp3')
music.play()

pyglet.app.run()
```

But I'd strongly suggest you use `pyglet.media.load()` and have a look [at the documentation](https://pyglet.readthedocs.org/en/latest/programming_guide/resources.html#loading-resources)

Comment: hi, I have audio file in certain directory so prefer with directory but this way I got different error   `'AVbin is required to decode compressed media')
pyglet.media.riff.WAVEFormatException: AVbin is required to decode compressed media`

Comment: @L_Oni I'm gonna quote the front page of pyglet here, `pyglet can optionally use AVbin to play back audio formats such as MP3`. The mp3 format and other formats are a encoded file format and thus hard to natively decode. If you do not wish to add another library please use `.wav` audio files instead.

Comment: problem is that I'm looking for solution to play mp3 file from gTTS without using of default player, just like simpleaudio does it with wav file. now have os.startfile, but I want use code for GUI, so default player is not the best idea

Comment: @L_Oni No where does it say you wanted to use `gTTS` in your question, nor do i understand how simpleaudio works. But you are confusing at the moment because you say you want "wav format just like simpleaudio" but you also say you are "looking for a solution to play mp3 files". Also what do you mean by "default player is not the best idea"? What default player? Your code and my code are virtually identical. The only difference is you lack `AVbin` to get `.mp3` format.

Comment: gTTS creates mp3 file, now I use os.startfile but it opens mp3 with default player from Windows, simple audio works with WAV file, but plays it without default player, so I'm looking for solution play mp3 this way, need it for GUI. maybe you know how to avoid player using with os.startfile or how to figure out with AVbin, I got this error with mp3 created by gTTS, but error contains `media.riff.WAVEFormatException`  so...I don't know

Comment: @L_Oni I have already written the answer for that?! **install AVbin** and use the code i wrote in my answer... That code opens `.mp3` files anywhere on your harddrive.