# how can I use pyglet write a music player can play a music list

Tags: python, pyglet

I want to play a music list with pyglet, who can help me, thanks!

```
music = pyglet.resource.media('music/file.ogg')
music.play()
pyglet.app.run()
```

Comment: please provide a `mcve` - [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: i dont know how to write, sorry

Comment: how can i do?   i want to play music list continuously,but it just can play one not a list, i tried `sourcefroup` but i am not make it.can someone tell me how to modify my code,to make it can play 

    `sound = pyglet.media.load('music/file.ogg')
    player = pyglet.media.Player()
    looper = pyglet.media.SourceGroup(sound.audio_format, None)
    looper.queue(sound)
    player.queue(looper)
    player.play()`

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the top 4 most recent [pyglet tagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pyglet) questions on SO right now is all related to this very specific thing..

I pulled [one of them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36819585/play-mp3-without-default-player) out of the hat and voila:

```
import pyglet

music = pyglet.media.load(r'./music/file.ogg')
music.play()

pyglet.app.run()
```

Please keep in mind that the only standard/normal format that is easily processed is **.wav** files, there for if you want to play mp3 or ogg files pyglet **requires [AVbin](https://avbin.github.io/AVbin/Download.html)**!

Quote from pyglet [front-page](https://bitbucket.org/pyglet/pyglet/wiki/Home):

> use AVbin to play back audio formats such as MP3, OGG/Vorbis and WMA, and video formats such as DivX, MPEG-2, H.264, WMV and Xvid